# Equation of elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve with a 3-torsion point $T$. One can write a Weierstrass equation for $E$. If I define $C := E/\langle T \rangle$, what is the Weierstrass equation for $C$? Is it just the equation given at the top of page 4 in this paper [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.4963v2.pdf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the curve $\hat{E}$ in that paper is the correct curve.  It is an elliptic curve $\hat{E}$ with an isogeny $E \to \hat{E}$ whose kernel is $\langle T \rangle$, so it's the right curve for $E/\langle T \rangle$.